# if-else statement does not seem to work correctly after 3rd iteration

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

I have this program below that I have written to print out the multiplication table from 1 to 12. I also am wanting to print 1 to 12 down the side seperated by a few spaces and a "|". I have an if-else statement set up to reduce the number of spaces required depending on how many digits are in that number, but when I run the code below, it prints out the first two rows, and then stops.

Maybe I have been staring at code for too long today, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it does this.

By the way, the table itself prints out fine when I remove the if-else statement at the end and just have "System.out.println(print);" after the nested for-loop.

```
import java.util.*;


public class MultiplicationTable{

  public static void main(String[] args){

    int n = 12;
    int temp;
    int length;

    String[][] table = new String[n][n];

    /**Assign values to the array*/
    /**These are the rows*/
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){

        /**These are the columns*/
        for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++){

            /**this is the current multiplication value*/
            temp = i*j;
            /**assigning the value to it's place in the array*/
            table[i-1][j-1] = String.valueOf(temp);

            /**determining how many spaces are required to keep the table ordered*/
            length = String.valueOf(temp).length();                
            if(length==1){
                table[i-1][j-1] = table[i-1][j-1]+"   ";
            }
            else if(length==2){
                table[i-1][j-1] = table[i-1][j-1]+"  ";
            }
            else{
                table[i-1][j-1] = table[i-1][j-1]+" ";
            }
        }

    }

    /**This is to print out the array*/
    String print;

    for(int x = 0; x<n; x++){

        print = "";
        for(int y=0; y<n; y++){
            print = print + String.valueOf(table[x][y]);
        }

        /**This is for determining how many spaces are needed in front of the lines*/
        length = String.valueOf(x+1).length();

        //This is for error testing
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println(length);
        System.out.println("");
        //End of error testing

        if(x==1){

            System.out.println(x+"  |"+print);
        }
        else if(x==2){
            System.out.println(x+" |"+print);
        }
    }

  }  

}
```

Comment: I'm not going to debug the above code to see if this suggestion works, but your `if(x==1)` should be `if(length==1)`. Please learn to use a debugger to step through your code so you can see the flow for yourself.

Comment: Ahh dammit. Thank you. You are, of course, correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point of `table`. I would use formatted output and something like

```
int n = 12;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        if (j != 0) {
            System.out.print(" | ");
        }
        System.out.printf("% 4d", (1+i) * (1+j));
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Output is (as requested)

```
 1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |    5 |    6 |    7 |    8 |    9 |   10 |   11 |   12
 2 |    4 |    6 |    8 |   10 |   12 |   14 |   16 |   18 |   20 |   22 |   24
 3 |    6 |    9 |   12 |   15 |   18 |   21 |   24 |   27 |   30 |   33 |   36
 4 |    8 |   12 |   16 |   20 |   24 |   28 |   32 |   36 |   40 |   44 |   48
 5 |   10 |   15 |   20 |   25 |   30 |   35 |   40 |   45 |   50 |   55 |   60
 6 |   12 |   18 |   24 |   30 |   36 |   42 |   48 |   54 |   60 |   66 |   72
 7 |   14 |   21 |   28 |   35 |   42 |   49 |   56 |   63 |   70 |   77 |   84
 8 |   16 |   24 |   32 |   40 |   48 |   56 |   64 |   72 |   80 |   88 |   96
 9 |   18 |   27 |   36 |   45 |   54 |   63 |   72 |   81 |   90 |   99 |  108
10 |   20 |   30 |   40 |   50 |   60 |   70 |   80 |   90 |  100 |  110 |  120
11 |   22 |   33 |   44 |   55 |   66 |   77 |   88 |   99 |  110 |  121 |  132
12 |   24 |   36 |   48 |   60 |   72 |   84 |   96 |  108 |  120 |  132 |  144
```

Answer (score -1):

If x is 1, you print something; if x is 2, you print something (the same thing, but whatever); otherwise, you do nothing.  Where is the confusion?

Comment: This answer is poor mostly because the question is poor, but the answer is poor nonetheless.